# cannot read property '_id' of undefined when user signed out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to set conditional logic using user id so that if the authenticated user is the same user who created this post, don't show the like button. This works however if the user is not signed in, I get this error `cannot read property '_id' of undefined`. Basically the user is undefined because no user is authenticated when the user is signed out so how do I handle this without getting this error and the app crashing? How can I solve this error but still keep this logic with the user id?
Thanks

Post.js

```
  ...
      .then((result) => {
        const {
          user: { _id },
        } = isAuthenticated();
        let updatedPost = { ...post };
        updatedPost.likes.push(id);
        setPost(updatedPost);
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  const showLikeIcon = () => {
    const {user: {_id}} = isAuthenticated()
    return (
      <span>
        {/* if user is not signed in, or user = author of post, don't display like icon */}
        {post.author && post.author.id === _id || !isAuthenticated() ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <img
            src={Like}
            onClick={() => {
              like(id);
            }}
            alt="Like icon"
          />
        )}
      </span>
    );
  };


export default Post;
```

isAuthenticated()

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwt'));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your code, I guess when user signed in your `isAuthenticated()` return data structure like:

```
{
  ...
  user: {
     _id: id,
     ...
  }
}
```

So you can do `{user: {_id}} = isAuthenticated()`. But when user not signed in, it just return `false` so `isAuthenticated().user` is `undefined`, that cause the error.

To fix this, you can change your code to something like:

```
const showLikeIcon = () => {
  const {user} = isAuthenticated();
  return (
    <span>
      // if no user then it will not call user._id
      {(!user || (post.author && post.author.id === user._id)) ? (
        ""
      ) : (
        <img
          src={Like}
          onClick={() => {
            like(id);
          }}
          alt="Like icon"
        />
      )}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is undefined, you can't get it's props.
for example when `user` is `undefined` and hasn't any value, if you want to get `user._id` you'll get this error:
`cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

May be you have to do something like this:

```js
const isAuthenticatedValue = isAuthenticated();
const user = isAuthenticatedValue?._id;
```

the `?` operator prevents the error

- **I don't know what's going inside your `isAuthenticated()` function.
  If I know, I can help better**

Ex:

```js
const person;
console.log(person?.name);
```

this won't throw any error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added the code in `isAuthenticated()` to my question. I've just tried the code you provided which removed the error but the logic isn't working at all now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to npm install body-parser, then add

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser());
```

to the top of your code. This is also assuming you are using Express.

This should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just check if the `user` object has value first before accessing the _id. For example

```js
if(!user) return;

const { user: { _id }} = isAuthenticated();
```

So we use a guard clause to check that `user` is defined before running other parts of the code